# Creating indexed 'groups' in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I have a data of size 1000 * 500

I want to put the data into 100 groups by partitioning the rows into sizes of 10
I want to do something like:

```
for i = 1 : 100   %i = group
    Group[i] = data(10*i : 10*i - 9, 1:500);
end
```

I'd like to know how I can do this without manually creating Group1,...Group100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want 3d arrays:

```
groups = permute(reshape(data, [10 100 500]), [1 3 2]);
```

Now `groups(:, :, 1)` is a 10x500 matrix, group 1.

Comment: Wow thank you! 
Now, how would I do this if I want to exclude the first row?
So, the first group would be rows 2-10, as opposed to 1-10

Comment: Oh right, I am quite new to this business. Thank you for the reminder. Also, thank you for the help.